# Condition works separately but not as OR

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have two conditional statements that are the following :

```
if( isset( $query_string['page'] ) && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/') !== false && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/page/') === false ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_feed() && !is_admin() && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/') !== false && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/page/') === false ) {
```

The last condition in both if statements is :

```
strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/page/') === false
```

I would like to change the last condition for both, which would be in plain English :

If all criteria are matched and the URL contains either *'/blog/page/'* or *'/blog/tag/'* do something.

When I interchange the last condition from *'/blog/page/'* to *'/blog/tag/'* the code works. As soon as I try to have both at the same time, the code doesn't work anymore.

I've tried to change the `&&` to `and` and use `||` for the or condition, in order to keep the right precedence. I have tried to put them between parenthesis in order to handle the precedence, none of them worked.

I even tried :

```
strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/page/') || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/tag/') === false
```

Which didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// Your code says "=== false" (doesn't match)
// but your English description says "contains either '/blog/page/' or '/blog/tag/'" (match)
// This assumes you want what your English description says


/**
 * Returns a boolean indicating if the given URI part is found
 */
function match($uriPart)
{
    return strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $uriPart) !== false;
}

/**
 * Returns a boolean indicating if the given URI part is not found
 */
function doesNotMatch($uriPart)
{
    return strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $uriPart) === false;
}

// In this case, "match('/blog/')" is redundant because you're checking for other strings which contain it. 
// Nevertheless, I'm leaving it as-is.
if( isset( $query_string['page'] ) && match('/blog/') && (match('/blog/page/') || match('/blog/tag/'))) {
...

// In this case, "match('/blog/')" is redundant because you're checking for other strings which contain it. 
// Nevertheless, I'm leaving it as-is.
if( $query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_feed() && !is_admin() && match('/blog/') && (match('/blog/page/') || match('/blog/tag/'))) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what was messing everything up. Thank you very much for your clear and precise answer